# Retrieve a deleted file after SVN undo add

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I added a file to my project and then by mistake I clicked `undo add`, and now I can't find the file. Any idea how I can retrieve the deleted file please?

Comment: Undo add should not touch the file on disk in any way. The file should still be in the same location on disk.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't know, but it just disappeared once i did that. May be because this new file was a copy of another file in the same directory but with many modifications done to it?